# Android Search Dialog how do I restrict input to numbers only?

Tags: android, validation, search-dialog

I'm building a zip code search page for my Android app so I want to force the user to enter 5 numeric digits.  I've searched everywhere and I don't see any way to for the [Search Dialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html).  I know that text entry fields can be set to a numeric type, how do I do that for the Search Dialog?

Comment: <searchable has option for android:inputType="inputType"

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/searchable-config.html#searchable-element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Searchable Configuration

In That you can Specify

```
android:inputType="inputType"
android:imeOptions="imeOptions"
```

For more information

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/searchable-config.html

Comment: Thanks, since you gave a more complete answer I'll give you the check!

Answer (score 1):

In the `searchable` that you have defined, you can set the input type.

For more info refer here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/searchable-config.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, I don't know how I missed this.  Too bad I can't give out more than one check mark here!